# Ensure one function executes once at a time

Tags: c++, mfc

How can i ensure a function to be called once and it can only be called again after the tasks of previous call is fully executed.

I am talking about a event generated function call in MFC c++ VS2019 windows, so calling the function is not controllable.

for example

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CMyWnd2, CWnd)
   ON_MESSAGE(WM_MYMESSAGE, OnMyMessage)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()

// inside the class declaration
afx_msg LRESULT OnMyMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam);

LRESULT CMyWnd2::OnMyMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(wParam);
   UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);

   // The task here might take some time to finish execution.

   return 0;
}
```

I want to ensure when `OnMyMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)` is being executed, any other call to this function must be ignored.

Comment: Do you know how to use `std::mutex`?

Comment: No, I will search and see.

Comment: Searching for keywords on Google is not the most efficient way to learn C++. The only practical way to do so is with a good C++ book. Every book will have many chapters on multithreading, and discussing C++'s thread library, and how to use mutexes and condition variables.

Comment: @sam: Reentrancy is not restricted to multithreading.

Comment: You need to tell us what `// The task here might take some time` roughly does. Is it just some computation? If this is the case, then `OnMyMessage` cannot be called again untill the "task" is finished. Or it there a message loop? We need more background information

Comment: Task roughly runs some adb commands, accepts client connection and then update some texts in UI. The message indicates new device connection. When multiple devices are connected at once, i want to execute 'OnMyMessage' one by one devices.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear how `OnMyMessage` can be called when you're still in `OnMyMessage`.

But anyway maybe this helps: it won't *prevent* the call of `OnMyMessage`, but once in `OnMyMessage` we just check if there is another ongoing `OnMyMessage` and in that case we just do nothing.

```
LRESULT CMyWnd2::OnMyMessage(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
   UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(wParam);
   UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lParam);

   static bool inMyMessage;

   if (inMyMessage)
     return 0;

   inMyMessage = true;

   // The task here might take some time to finish execution.

   inMyMessage = false;    
   return 0;
}
```